# SASweave and Sweave.sty

Tags: filesystem-access

I recently installed SASweave on a linux machine (RHEL 6 to be exact) for a group of developers, but they currently must copy a file called SasWeave.sty to their current project directory in order for SASweave to work properly.  Each user has numerous projects and must keep copies of this file in each.  I know almost nothing about SASweave or LaTeX but it seems that I should be able to set a system wide search path to point to this file (currently located at /usr/local/SASweave/SasWeave.sty) or alternatively copy this file to a location in the existing search path.

I've seen some discussion around this issue on stackexchange about modifying texmf.cnf but frankly the solutions are way above my head and I am baffled.  Can someone clearly explain the steps I need to take in order to get SASweave to find this file?  I would like to avoid having each user set an environment variable if possible.  Ideally, one system-wide setting that will propagate to all users would be preferable.  I have root access to the machine if that helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question asks how to make common files accessible to users.  so i've changed the tag to something more suitable than [tex-core].

Answer (score 1):

I am a SAS programmer who uses Windows
and have been asked to provide some guidance.

from the SASweave home page:

http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~rlenth/SASweave/

> Linux/Unix notes
>  SASweave uses awk scripts (actually, gawk or nawk are
>   required, because we need the ability to load more than one awk script
>   at a time).   You copy the scripts to a suitable location, the
>   associated shell scripts  sasweave and sastangle  to a location in the
>   PATH,  and the file SasWeave.sty to a location in the TEXINPUTS path.
>
> You will need to  edit sasweave and sastangle so that they can find
>   these scripts.

So, back to the unix krewe,
from my knowledge of Windows and SAS configuration files
it seems to me that the files sasweave and sastangle 
contain allocations of libraries and folders to search for the file SASweave.sty

hth

Ron Fehd
SAS-L's macro maven

TeXhax {SAS} macro maven